# RequestMapping doesn't redirect

Tags: spring, jsp, url

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/{Id}",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String searchCity( @PathVariable ("Id") Long Id) {
         mymethod.something(id);
          return "successpage";
        }
```

When I'm trying to write some number it print me Eror 404 resource is not available, but when I write {Id} ("7DId7D" smthing like this) it redirects me to succespage, What is the problem? Help me please...

Comment: Please provide the URL you used to test. One succeeded and one failed.

Comment: checkout the server log what is it saying

Comment: http://localhost:8080/MyCountryProject/%7BId%7D - succeeded

Comment: http://localhost:8080/MyCountryProject/7 - failed

Comment: thanks for your answers guys. Arun, when i can find server.log?

Answer (score 2):

The information you provided conflicts with known behavior of Spring MVC

- `http://localhost:8080/MyCountryProject/7` should maps to searchCity fine
- `http://localhost:8080/MyCountryProject/%7Bld%7D` should not even map to searchCity

I would check following to further isolate the problem:

- Are you sure you're testing against the right controller? If your controller has `@RequestMapping("myController")` then your URL would be `http://localhost:8080/MyCountryProject/MyController/7`
- Are you sure you're posting with the correct HTTP method? If you're HTTP form is POST, it wouldn't map to searchCity method
- The conversion from string into Long is done by Spring MVC builtin property editor, did you install your own property editor? If so debug this